# why is dict2xml is not maintaing same order as in input dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a data stored in dictionary format that needs to be written into an xml file format..

I am trying to use dict2xml module..

I am seeing tat the order of items in dictionary is not maintained in the xml file.

The dictionary input i am using is a OrderedDict().

What could be the reason. Any other better module other than dict2xml that can be used?

For example..

```
$ ipython
Python 3.5.1 (default, Oct 28 2016, 14:29:41)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.2.2 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: from collections import OrderedDict

In [2]: myDict = OrderedDict()

In [3]: myDict['simpleVal'] = 1

In [4]: dictVal = OrderedDict()

In [5]: dictVal['simpleVal1'] = 2

In [6]: dictVal['listVal'] = ['a','b','c']

In [7]: myDict['dictVal'] = dictVal

In [8]: myDict['listVal1'] = ['d','e','f','g']

In [9]: myDict
Out[9]:
OrderedDict([('simpleVal', 1),
             ('dictVal',
              OrderedDict([('simpleVal1', 2), ('listVal', ['a', 'b', 'c'])])),
             ('listVal1', ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g'])])

In [10]: from dict2xml import dict2xml

In [11]: dict2xml(myDict)
Out[11]: '<dictVal>\n  <listVal>a</listVal>\n  <listVal>b</listVal>\n  <listVal>c</listVal>\n  <simpleVal1>2</simpleVal1>\n</dictVal>\n<listVal1>d</listVal1>\n<listVal1>e</listVal1>\n<listVal1>f</listVal1>\n<listVal1>g</listVal1>\n<simpleVal>1</simpleVal>'
```

The Actual output as you can see is:

```
<dictVal>
    <listVal>a</listVal>
    <listVal>b</listVal>
    <listVal>c</listVal>
     <simpleVal1>2</simpleVal1>
</dictVal>
<listVal1>d</listVal1>
<listVal1>e</listVal1>
<listVal1>f</listVal1>
<listVal1>g</listVal1>
<simpleVal>1</simpleVal>
```

But as per my order i have given my output should have been

```
<simpleVal>1</simpleVal>
<dictVal>
    <simpleVal1>2</simpleVal1>
    <listVal>a</listVal>
    <listVal>b</listVal>
    <listVal>c</listVal>
</dictVal>
<listVal1>d</listVal1>
<listVal1>e</listVal1>
<listVal1>f</listVal1>
<listVal1>g</listVal1>
```

Comment: could you update your post with: your code, input, expected output, actual output. thanks.

Comment: Sorry have updated the query..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `dict2xml` sorts the names before converting them to xml.

I can't really tell why... I don't know if that behavior is document anywhere.

From the [code](https://github.com/delfick/python-dict2xml/blob/master/dict2xml/logic.py#L126):

```
def convert(self):
    ...
    if typ == 'mapping':
        for key in sorted(data): <--- SORTING THE KEYS!
            item = data[key]
            children.append(Node(key, "", item, iterables_repeat_wrap=self.iterables_repeat_wrap))
```